# Python GUI Library for Ubuntu Core on Raspberry Pi CM3+

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, pygame

I am running ubuntu core on a rpi CM3+.

I have noticed that tkinter is not included in the ubuntu core for rpi. Also, since sdl libraries are missing I cannot install pygame either.

Any ideas on how I can proceed ?

Comment: Did you try to install the `python3-tk` package?

Answer (score 0):

for pygame you can use

```
sudo apt install python3-pygame
```

and for tkinter

```
sudo apt install python3-tk
```

Comment: It is an ubuntu core env, so there is no apt